# я кажется отупел Unity void #C

Tags: unity3d

Возможно я этот момент пропустил но мне надо обратиться В ОДНОМ И ТОМЖЕ СКРИПТЕ

```
public void oncl()
{
    print("Выполнение")
}

public void gar()
{
    print ("Ты перешел в другую функцию Gar")
}
```

в пример здесь надо перейти после принта в другую функцию gar как это сделать

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-c)

Comment: Поучи базу по языку...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, что ты хочешь сделать то:

```
public void oncl()
{
    print("Выполнение");
    gar();
}

public void gar()
{
    print ("Ты перешел в другую функцию Gar");
}
```

На будущее, не забывай про `;`.